# Sencha touch picker Error: Cannot read property 'dom' of null

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have created one picker in sencha touch.

Then added into viewport like this:

```
Ext.Viewport.add(picker);
picker.show();
```

Then when I try to remove it from viewport it is throwing js error in console.
code is:

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(picker, true);
```

Cannot read property 'dom' of null in Container.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(picker, true);
```

You need to put above code in defer as below. It requires at least more delay.

```
Ext.defer(function(){
      Ext.Viewport.remove(picker, false);
}, 500);
```

Comment: thanks but I require 500ms time for defer. 'cause after destroying the picker code try to execute some code in Container.js hence we required to destroy picker after execution of all code.